# wpf text editor touch handles

Tags: .net, wpf, touch, editor

There is very nice feature in Excel 2013 on touch screens. When I touch its text editor, it will show handles that make much easier to select the text.

[image: touch handles]

Someone told me that these handles are enabled automatically in .NET 4.5. I've tried VS 2013 with WPF project and they don't appear. Tried DevExpress controls suite - no luck. I couldn't even find any mention of such thing in google.

So, is it possible to implement in some simple way?